# Using Redux with react-grid-layout

Tags: reactjs, redux, middleware, react-grid-layout

I'm using react-grid-layout (RGL) to implement this use case with two considerations

- to keep the state of the app including GridItems' child components
- enable communication between GridItems' child components (events,
  streams of data,

etc)

Inspecting the RGL tree on React Dev tools I can see that there are many intermediate components.

I was wondering if anyone has implemented a similar scenario, and if theres a way to use a Redux store and pass it down the RGL tree to GridItems' child components.

```
<ResponsiveReactGridLayout
<ReactGridLayout
<div
<GridItem
<DraggableCore
<Resizable
<div
<UserChildComponent
```

Many thanks,

FØ

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own redux-noob question:

The fact that there are many invisible elements in the tree doesn't prevent passing the store down the  element. Our custom-defined  components (i.e., subcomponents of GridItem and leaves on the component tree) can get the store using the redux's connect as conventionally.

React-grid-layout

```
class Layout extends React.PureComponent {
render() {
return (
  <div>
    <ResponsiveReactGridLayout
      onBreakpointChange={this.onBreakpointChange}
      {...this.props}
    >
      {_.map(this.state.items, el => this.createElement(el))}
    </ResponsiveReactGridLayout>
  </div>


export default connect(state => state)(Layout);
```

The custom-defined component

```
class myCustomComponent extends Component {

export default connect(state => state) (myCustomComponent);
```

The resulting component tree in ReactDevTools,

```
<Connect(Layout)
 <ResponsiveReactGridLayout
  <ReactGridLayout
   <div
    <GridItem
     <DraggableCore
      <Resizable
       <div
        <Connect(UserChildComponent)
```

and the redux store and dispatch are part of their props.